# Mathematica keeps turning text cells into inputs

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I am using version 11.3 of Mathematica and when I make my notebook files I make sure to convert specific cells into text and deselect "evaluatable", yet when I save and reopen the file, the text cell is an input cell. How can I stop this?

Comment: What steps do you follow _exactly_ to modify the cells in your notebook?

Comment: If you want it to literally be text, why not change the style to `Text`?

Comment: Additionally, what @user6014 said.  I'm not seeing the behavior you describe.  (Probably.  Of course, an `Input` cell that is not evaluatable is still an `Input` cell.  it does not become a `Text` cell.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell for sure without knowing what you are doing exactly, but I suspect that you *aren't* really creating text cells.

This is how it is normally done:

Position the input cursor between cells (not within a cell). It will look like a horizontal line (not vertical).

Now choose Format -> Style -> Text from the menu.  I believe the shortcut is Command-7 on Mac and Alt-7 on other platforms. This will create a Text cell.

Do not change cell properties like "Evaluatable". It is not necessary.